Calculation of concentration for standard curve
for my enzyme fluorescent assay measurements in soil samples I have to calculate my standard curves. In a protocol, I have found this table where I cannot comprehend the reasoning how the author has gotten to the numbers in the column "Concentration (in nM)".
As a recap: There is already 200µl of buffer in the microplate well, then step by step a stock solution of 10µM or 50µM is added as presented in the table. (so in sum a volume of 250µl in every well)
What is the calculation reasoning behind the column "Concentration (in nM)"?
Thank you!


Add your attempts at calculating the concentrations. What is the dilution formula? What is the relationship between micro- and nano- prefixes?
